# Web request not going through with TLS 1.2 enabled in registry in C# application

Tags: c#, tls1.2

I have a C# windows application and I am trying to make a **web request** on a URL using `HttpWebRequest`. I have enabled `TLS 1.2` in the registry at below location

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2`

At the same time, I have `TLS 1.0` and `TLS 1.1` disabled from the registry.

while I make calls to the URL, it fails until and unless I add the below code in my solution

```cs
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But I do not want to hardcode TLS value in my code.

Is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not set the TLS version in a config file so it is not hard coded.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the Registry setting, this affects all applications. If you're running this code in Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, then you can use a switch, checking the System version and leave `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` if the System >= 8.1 and you're using .Net Frameworks 4.7.1+, otherwise set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` (not `|=`)